# Get a random, high port number that is still available

Tags: sockets, posix, tcp

Suppose I want to run a TCP/IP service on some port for IPC. As I'm passing the port number to the processes I want to communicate with anyway, the port number doesn't matter. What's the best way to get a random, high (usually >49152) port number that is still available from the system? Is there something in POSIX I can use?

I know FTP servers need this frequently.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't specify a port number the OS will pick automatically an [ephemeral port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) number for you.

From [Choosing the Port Number](http://cs.nyu.edu/bacon/phd-thesis/diss/node29.html#SECTION00713000000000000000):

> New server software should strive to avoid depending on a specific port number, especially if it is user-level software that is not ineluctably tied to a well-known port. Fortunately, this is easily done by requesting port 0, which instructs the system to choose an ephemeral port number.

Comment: Yes, port 0 allows the OS to pick a random available port for you.  On the other hand, using port 0 does not allow you to specify a range of ports for the OS to pick from.  If you are behind a firewall/router, for instance, then being able to use port ranges becomes more important.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Any firewall that is configured to only allow a range of outbound ports is misconfigured and should be fixed. As the Socket API doesn't support that, it places a burden on applications that they cannot meet, as well as being entirely pointless from the security point of view.

Comment: @EJP: You are assuming port binding is only being done for *outbound* connections. FTP is a good example of when a client may need to bind sockets for *inbound* connections, for active-mode transfers.

Answer (score 6):

Ephemeral ports can do that. Your OS will assign you a port from the free port pool.

There is some C code, BSD-licensed, doing this [here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid3DEF34D031397FD18E8EBEB19581F051C207E3B5.aspx?s=ephemeral+sock)

In Python, you can specify a `('', 0)` socket.AF_INET address pair for the same purpose, e.g. `sock.bind(('', 0))`

Comment: What Python function should we call with arguments ('127.0.0.1', 0)?

Comment: @Nordlöw - [bind](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind)

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to bind to port number 0, the system will bind your socket to an "ephemereal" random port.
You can then get the port with `getsockname` (in C).

In ruby:

```
s = TCPServer.new('localhost', 0) #You can also use nil instead of 0
s.addr[1] #The obtained port number
```

Comment: Ephemereal ? How long it would last ? I hope until the server stops.

Comment: @yucer It means that it's not a fixed number associated with a particular fixed service like 80 for HTTP. It'll still last until you close or until the OS closes it for you when your process terminates.

Comment: I think the constructor has changed. See: http://bit.ly/1o9DDJb
Also the addr attribute is now server_address

Comment: @yucer ruby != python

Answer (score -2):

You can use my small C library: https://github.com/yegor256/random-tcp-port

Compile it and run on your machine. It will output a random TCP port available.

Comment: Which will then immediately become available again for someone else as soon as it exits. This is completely pointless.

Comment: But this is exactly what you suggested a few answers below, and all other aswers also suggest :) My library just makes it easier to get

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Assigning random ports is already part of the system -- all you got to do is request port number 0 and you'll get a random port which you can get with `getsockname`. If you close the socket though, you have no guarantee that that old ephemereal port number will be still available.

Comment: @yegor256 Yes, don't separate binding and finding a random port, and simply bind to port 0.

Comment: @PSkocik what if need to separate binding and finding? That's what my tool is for.

Comment: I wish there was a tool that would allow me to seperate the two. I've even started a question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121211/linux-properly-reserve-a-random-tcp-port-for-a-child-process . But your tool doesn't solve the problem. It only creates a library for whats achievable with approx. 3 lines of C code.

Answer (score -9):

The only way is to loop through the desired port range, attempting to bind a socket to each port one at a time until you find one that is successful.

Comment: No, it isn't the only way. Binding to port zero is another way, and an infinitely better way. QED