# Linux -- properly reserve a random TCP port for a child process

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have a 3rd-party script that starts a server on a given port.
I don't care what port I start it at, and I don't want to hog any ports, so what I've been doing is (pardon my ruby):

```
 ephemereal_server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 0)
  port = ephemereal_server.local_address.ip_port.to_s
  ephemereal_server.close
  return port
  #...
  spawn("script", "--port", port, ...)
```

I suppose the above is technically wrong because I suppose that by closing the ephemereal server, I lose ownership of that ephemereal port, and I'm not guaranteed that that port will still be available at the spawning part.

So my question is, can I do this correctly and reserve a random port for a child process?

I realize I can just pass 0 as the port CLI argument to the child process and then check what port it's listening on, however, that will only work if the child process will only listen on one port, or else I won't know which port corresponds to the 0 passed as the CLI port argument.

Comment: I guess the only method to reserve a port is to keep the socket opened. Pass its descriptor to the child process.